# How to "Center" listview items in a column

Tags: html, css, wpf, xaml, listview

Seem no matter where I put the `HorizentalAlignment = "Center"` in my `ListViewColumn` it doesn't effect the outcome.

This is all I have tried so far,

```
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Device name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DeviceName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content=" GPS Signal " />
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image Width="13" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Path=GpsSignalImagePath}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

As you can see it's mentioned in `Grid` and also in `Image` itself but no luck. The result shows up aligned to left as it's shown in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the `HorizontalAlignment` inside `ItemsPanelTemplate` like this

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: @har7, but since I already have `<ListView.View>` I won't be able to use the second property such as `<ListView.ItemPanel>`. Are you suggesting to remove the View?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` of `ListViewItem` from style to alter alingment of cell's content :

```
<ListView ....>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ......
    ......
</ListView>
```